# Definite Integral Problem using substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve $$ \int_0^\pi \frac {x} {1+\sin x} dx $$ using $\sin x = \frac {2\tan(x/2)} {1+\tan^2(x/2)}$ and the substitution $t = \tan(x/2)$.
I tried doing this but I got to a point where my integral limits were $0$ to $\infty
$. This happened when I substituted for $\tan(x/2)$
Is there a way of doing this using this substitution only?
And also why does this happen?

**UPDATE**: What I did -
$$ I = \int_0^\pi \frac {\pi-x} {1+\sin x} dx = \int_0^\pi \frac {\pi} {1+ \sin x} dx - I$$
Using $\sin x = \frac {2\tan(x/2)} {1+\tan^2(x/2)}$
$$ $$
$$ 2I = \int_0^\pi \frac {\pi} {1+\sin x} dx = \pi\int_0^\pi \frac {\sec^2(x/2)} {1+ \tan^2(x/2)+2 \tan(x/2)} dx$$
Now if there were no limits, this could've been solved easily by $t = \tan x$.
But I can't do that because if I did, the limits would become $0$ to $\infty$.
A way to solve this would be multiplying and dividing by $1+ \sin x$ but I don't want to do that. I want to use $t=\tan x$

Comment: Maybe you should try integration by parts first to get rid of that free $x$ on the top there.

Comment: Set $x\rightarrow x-\pi$ and see what happpens..nearly the same question was asked a few days ago by the user @bui so have a look in his profile

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Alternatively, by the change of variable $u=\pi-x$, one gets
$$
I=\int_0^\pi \frac {x} {1+\sin x} dx=\int_0^\pi \frac {\pi-u} {1+\sin (\pi-u)} du=\pi\int_0^\pi \frac {1} {1+\sin u} du-I
$$ the latter integral being easier to evaluate.

Comment: Always the same old good trick !

Answer (score 1):

After the main symmetry trick, another symmetry trick and a rationalization:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{du}{1+\sin u}=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\sin u}{\cos^2 u}\,du =2\left[\tan u-\frac{1}{\cos u}\right]_{0}^{\pi/2}=\color{red}{\large2}.$$

Comment: I don't want to use rationalization, I want to do it using the substitution u = tanx. Tricks are fine but the substitution has to be that.

Comment: @AnswerQuicklyPlease: you still have to split the integration range in halves since $\sin(x)$ is not injective on $(0,\pi)$. And after that, rationalization leads to the solution way faster than the given substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If we *must* solve the problem with the suggested substitution, the integral becomes $\int_0^\infty\frac{4\arctan t dt}{(1+t)^2}$. The identity $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt=\int_0^1\left(f(t)+\tfrac{1}{t^2}f\left(\tfrac{1}{t}\right)\right)dt$ changes this to $\int_0^1\frac{2\pi dt}{(1+t)^2}=\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the limits $(0, \infty)$ by reexpressing the anti-derivative without $ \tan \frac x2$, i.e

$$ \int\frac {1} {1+\sin x} dx = \int\frac {\sec^2\frac x2} {1+ \tan^2 \frac x2 +2 \tan \frac x2} dt\\
=-\frac {2} {1+ \tan \frac x2} = -\frac{2 \sin\frac x2}{\sin \frac x2+\cos \frac x2}$$